# What is the solution for daily backup only changed files (with log) in Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, windows-server-backup

We are a small team and working on a project that has huge file sizes which shared from a Windows Server running machine.
After some losing important files, corrupted files and etc... we decided to make a daily backup procedure to prevent that issues.

---

Now, What is the solution to make an automatic daily backup system to backup only changed files (with KEEPING previous files) to a San storage or external hard drive or etc...?

1 - What should i do?

---

2 - And what is the best to us:

We have in maximum 4 TB files on server.

San storage disk, External Hard drive or something else?

---

In addition, The server is working 7/24 But we don't care about server downtime, because we could make it to backup that files in night.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regular Windows Backup to a large enough storage. What kind of storage does only matter if backup speed is an issue.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. But how Windows Server backups behaves? 

Is that replace the old files with modified files or keep both as i need? 

could you explain a little more. - Or maybe there is some project backup management to keep all versions of files during time? 

Thanks

Comment: It should be always incremental. I cannot tell you for sure, but just read the docs on Windows Server Backup (which you should anyway). Or just try it out with a small test backup job.

Answer (score -1):

**Windows 2008:** Schedule a daily task with Robocopy script to `/MIR` the source folder. Test and read the `/?` before you run the script.

**Windows 2008 R2:** Same solution as above, or use the built-in Windows Server Backup utility. R2 added support to save to network location. Add feature from Server Manager if it's not already installed. Robocopy does have more logging options though.

Comment: A simple robocopy script won't satisfy his requirements (`only changed files (with KEEPING previous files)`)

Comment: Yes, it would, just don't use `/MIR`if you want it to keep old files. `robocopy source destination *.* /e /copyall /LOG:backup.log`. If this was your reason for the downvote, kindly remove it.

Comment: It still would not work. Changed files would be overwritten. All the log dos is show what files are being backed up. No file history would be present.

Comment: Nowhere in the initial question does it specify to have the backups be incremental. "Keeping old files" will generally be the difference between the /DEL option used or not. I.e. files deleted from the source will/will not be deleted on the destination. My reply is still valid to the question that was asked, whereas you fail to mention that your solution won't be valid in case the OP is in fact running Windows Server 2008 (not R2) as the question is tagged as, and want to backup to anything other than local storage, as he mentions.